# Updating Cart issue on Shopify Checkout Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, cart, liquid

With reference to this page URL:

https://shop.betterbody.co/pages/autoship-provitalize

Select a bottle, the the page will look like this:

[checkout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnTOw.png)

We have an issue on our checkout page when we are about to update the quantity using the + and - buttons. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. You can add, it loads, it works. But when you minus the quantity, it does not return back to 0 (in which the selected product should automatically be removed). If it doesn't work, you have to type the number '0' in order to remove the product from the cart.

Need help to see what can be done to counter this issue.

There are some slight modifications made to the core theme, so I am not sure how this is affecting the page. We are using the 3rd party app from Shopify called 'ReCharge Recurring Billing & Subscriptions'.

If its possible we want the cart updating to be on the fly, without refreshing. Do we inject javascript/ajax into the core codes? or is there any other ways to counter this? Appreciate your kind help and input on this. Thanks in advance!